# Implementing optional trait requirement

Tags: rust

I am trying to find a way to group different traits so that the generic variable can hold these traits.

For example, I am trying to have T such it's with the traits io::Read + io::Write + io::Seek .
Now, that can be easily done in rust using the following code:

```
pub trait RWS:  io::Read + io::Write + io::Seek{}
impl<T> RWS for T where T: io::Read + io::Write  + io::Seek{}
```

However, the problem comes when trying to have a function that takes in BufReader, because BufReader doesn't implement io::Write.

Therefore,
is there a possibility to implement something that looks like the following for a general type that can be either one?

```
pub trait RWS:  io::Read || io::Write || io::Seek{}
impl<T> RWS for T where T: io::Read || io::Write  || io::Seek{}
```

Comment: What do you intend to use the `RWS` trait for? These three traits expose different functionality, so I do not quite understand how you could unify them under a single trait `RWS`.

Comment: @AlphaModder I am not trying to use all of them, i am trying to impose the requirement for either one of them. For RWS, I am trying to store a field in the struct ```io``` such that it can be one of (read,write,seek). this ```io``` field will change depending on the function called. That's why i want it to be flexible.

Comment: I see. So the type stored in this field will change over the struct's lifetime? Will it ever need to be multiple at once, or is being able to use it as exactly one of `Read`, `Write`, or `Seek` at a time sufficient?

Comment: @AlphaModder Yes, the type in that struct will change over the lifetime. I think I programmed it to use one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a field that can store anything implementing one of these three traits at a time, I would suggest using a simple enum:

```
enum RWS<'a> { // The lifetime parameter can be omitted if you will only be storing fields of `'static` type.
    Read(Box<dyn Read + 'a>),
    Write(Box<dyn Write + 'a>),
    Seek(Box<dyn Seek + 'a>),
}
```

You could add `from_read`, `from_write`, `from_seek` constructors to this enum for convenience, and match on it in your struct's methods.

However, there are some limitations to this approach. Since it takes ownership of the value and erases its concrete type, you cannot do something like the following:

```
let bufreader: std::io::BufReader = /* ... */;
self.rws = RWS::Read(Box::new(bufreader));
// later...
if let self.rws = RWS::Read(val) {
    self.rws = RWS::Seek(val); // compile error, even though `BufReader` impls `Seek`
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Enum and refactoring my code seems to be my only option here since there is no other way around it.